# Event handlers not thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, thread-safety

So i've read around that instead of calling a event directly with

```
if (SomeEvent != null)
   SomeEvent(this, null);
```

i should be doing

```
SomeEventHandler temp = SomeEvent;
if (temp != null)
    temp(this, null);
```

Why is this so? How does the second version become thread safe? What is the best practice?

Comment: Reading over the tentative, qualified answers here I get the sense that event handling in C# is tightly-coupled, error-prone, and not understood very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Events are really syntactic sugar over a list of delegates. When you invoke the event, this is really iterating over that list and invoking each delegate with the parameters you have passed.

The problem with threads is that they could be adding or removing items from this collection by subscribing/unsubscribing. If they do this while you are iterating the collection this will cause problems (I think an exception is thrown)

The intent is to copy the list before iterating it, so you are protected against changes to the list.

Note: It is however now possible for your listener to be invoked even after you unsubscribed, so you should make sure you handle this in your listener code.

Comment: Actually, it will not cause a problem while you iterate over the collection. The delegates in play here are immutable. The only problem is the split second before checking if anyone has subscribed and actually calling the event handlers. Once you've started executing those, no background changes will affect the current invocation.

Comment: Adding to Lasse V. Karlsen's comment, you can eliminate that last piece of race condition by using SomeEvent?.Invoke(...) instead of checking for null before the invokation.

Answer (score 32):

IMO, the other answers miss one key detail - that delegates (and therefore events) are *immutable*. The significance of this is that subscribing or unsubscribing an event handler *doesn't* simply append/remove to a list - rather, it *replaces* the list with a new one with an extra (or one less) item on it.

Since references are atomic, this means that at the point you do:

```
var handler = SomeEvent;
```

you now have a *rigid* instance that cannot change, even if in the next picosecond another thread unsubscribes (causing the *actual* event field to become `null`).

So you test for null and invoke it, and all is well. Note of course that there is *still* the confusing scenario of the event being *raised* on an object that thinks it unsubscribed a picosecond ago!

Comment: That addresses one concern, but is the replacement itself done safely in such a way to guarantee that all requested operations happen? I.e., if two threads try to subscribe distinct delegates at the same time, is it guaranteed that both will be subscribed in the end or is it possible for one of those subscriptions to silently fail?

Comment: @binki yes; it uses an interlocked exchange loop (modern compiler), or a synchronized (`lock`) region (older compilers)

Answer (score 5):

Best practice is the second form. The reason is that another thread might null or alter `SomeEvent` between the '`if`' test and the invocation.

Comment: Why can't that happen in the second statement?

Comment: The read is of `SomeEvent` is atomic, i.e. it happens all the way or nothing. Thus `temp` cannot be modified outside that thread due to being a local.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2010/03/3-races-with-net-events.html) is a good write up about .NET events and race conditions with threads.  It covers some common scenarios and has some good references in it.

Hope this helps.