# Calling an event handler in C#

Tags: c#, events

I've been trying to learn how to use event handlers in C# but I can't figure out what handler(this, e) does in the following code:

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Is it trying to call the event handler method (this) with the event (e)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448487

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It invokes all registered event listeners which are registered on the `ThresholdReached` event.

The `handler != null` check makes sure at least one listener is registered to that event.

In C# 6.0 and above you can use [Null Propagation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

```
handler?.Invoke(this, e);
```

---

`handler(this, e)` will call every registered event listener. Event listeners subscribe with help of the `+=` operator and unsubscribe with `-=` operator to that event.

`this` is there to give the event listener to know who raised the ThresholdReached event. Who was the sender of the event.

`e` is the event argument which is also passed into the listener method which can contain more useful informations about the ThresholdReached event e.g. *which* threshold was reached.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How might you register a listener to the event though?

Comment: With the += operator. Like in your other class yourInstanceWithTheEvent.ThresholdReached += SomeThresholdReachedHandler;

Answer (score 1):

It is raising a `ThresholdReached` event with arguments sender=this and eventarguments = e.
In fact, it is the same as the following;

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
    if (ThresholdReached != null)
    {
        ThresholdReached(this, e);
    }
}
```

If there are any listeners to this event; it will simply call listener delegates;

```
this.ThresholdReached += new EventHandler(Form1_ThresholdReached);
```

Then, when this event is raised `Form1_ThresholdReached` function will be called with `this` and `e` parameters.

Comment: @daryal: Imagine what happens if the last listener unsubscribes after the != null check.

Comment: @Oded does not the "handler" and the "ThresholdReached" point to the same reference? Sorry if i am missing some point.

Comment: @daryal - No. The invocation list is _copied_ to the `handler` reference. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) by Eric Lippert on the subject.

Comment: Maybe it helps to understand that an event is an instance variable which holds a reference to a MultiCastDelegate http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx If the last listener unsubscribes, it will remove that multicastdelegate instance and set the event to null.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken about events being multicast delegate instances. But read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx "Thread safe events" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example copies all registered handlers to the local variable `handler`, checks that the invocation list is not empty and invokes all members of the copied invocation list with the arguments `this` and `e`.

The reason for the fact that you get a snapshot of the current invocation list is that [delegates are immutable](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/delegates-are-immutable/). You get a reference to the current multicast delegate, and when handlers are added or removed the backing field points to a new delegate created from two immutable ones.

The usual reason to copy the invocation list to a local variable is some form of thread-safety: a handler could be unsubscribed between the usual nullity check (check that the invocation list isn't empty) and the actual invocation: that way you might accidentally fire an event with no handlers and a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it trying to call the event handler method (this) with the event (e)?

No, not literally. It is calling the event handler with the `EventArgs` e and using `this` as sender. It might as well be:

```
if (ThresholdReached != null)
{
    ThresholdReached(this, e);
}
```

Or, to circumvent the null check:

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached = delegate { };

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
    ThresholdReached(this, e);
}
```

But, as @Oded noted, the first piece isn't thread-safe, because `EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached` creates a copy of the handler, which is better explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582052/c-sharp-event-handlers-not-thread-safe).

Answer (score 0):

`handler` refers to your `ThresholdReached` event. So, if anyone is subscribing to `ThresholdReached` events, their registered handler will be called with arguments `this`and `e`.

Comment: Oh that makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is Triggering the `ThresholdReached` event. Passing a reference to itself, `this`. Passing arguments about the event in `e`.

Answer (score 0):

The call to handler represents a function call in another object or class.  When you create the object, you will be able to write a piece of code that looks like this:

```
obj.ThreasholdReached += new EventHandler(someFunction);
```

`someFunction` in that class will be defined like this

```
public someFunction(object sender, EventArgs e) {...}
```

the `OnThreasholdReached` function in the original object is what publishes the event to any other class that has assigned a function to the ThreasholdReached handler.  Using `handler` as a go-between is an entirely unnecessary extra step.  You are still saying `if ThreasholdReached != null`, its the same thing.

In Summary:  The line of code `handler(this, e)` is actually the call to whatever subscriber `someFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)` has been assigned to the ThreasholdReached event of the object.