# Clarifying events invocation

Tags: c#, events, delegates

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public class Button: Control
{
   public event EventHandler Click;
   protected void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
      if (Click != null) Click(this, e);
   }
```

}

The book explains the code above in the following way:

> The OnClick method in the Button class "raises" the Click event. The notion of raising an event is precisely equivalent to invoking the
>   delegate represented by the event — thus, there are no special
>   language constructs for raising events. Note that the delegate
>   invocation is preceded by a check that ensures the delegate is
>   non-null.

Why does it imply that there's only one delegate in the event when there's a delegate instance for every event-handler? An instance is an instance and an event can contain many delegate instances that connect to actual methods.

I'd greatly appreciate if someone can make sense of this paragraph for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This is in depth](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) and might not be exactly what you are looking for. But, it breaks down the differences between events and delegates in pretty good detail...taking it all the way to the IL.

Otherwise: [this SO has already been answered on a simpler basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-are-the-differences-between-delegates-and-events)

Comment: Why does it imply that there's only one delegate in the event when there's a delegate instance for every event-handler?

Answer (score 0):

> Now what does it mean by the "delegate represented by the event"?

This is how the event looks like *from the perspective* of the code that raises it. The event is raised using the standard method call syntax (as opposed to some "special" syntax), which in turn calls all the subscribed event handlers [in no particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645554/533120).

> And what does it mean by "a check that ensures the delegate is non-null"?

If there are no event handlers subscribed to the event, then the "delegate representing the event" is null. So to raise the event, you should do something like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public delegate void MyEventHandler(MyEventArg arg);

    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    void RaiseMyEvent(MyEventArg arg) {
        var handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null) // Any subscribers?
            handler(arg);
    }

}
```

BTW, copying the event to a local variable (`handler`) is considered a good practice, for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582595/533120).

Comment: Why does it imply that there's only one delegate in the event? I mean, the event is a function member that's declared with a delegate type. Meaning, instances of that delegate type referencing methods of that delegate type and signature are added to the event as event handlers.

Comment: @user2247389 _"Why does it imply that there's only one delegate in the event?"_ Because there is. That delegate then calls all the other delegates (i.e. event handlers subscribed to the event).

Comment: But a delegate can reference only one method, unless it's a composite delegate. We have each instance of the delegate type associated with one event handler. Where does this single delegate that calls the other delegates come from? Is it a composite delegate instance that's made of all the instance delegates in the event?

Comment: @user2247389 This is a "multi-cast" delegate. Where it "comes from" is an implementation detail.